# How to start sensors-applet

Tags: 11.04, sensors

I installed `lm-sensors hddtemp sensors-applet`. I am able to get output from `sensors`. But cant find how I can start `sensors-applet`. I didnt find Hardware Sensors (or anything that looks like `sensors-applet`) under `Right Click Panel > Add to Panel`

I am using Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your using unity under ubuntu 11.04 in which case unity doesn't support the sensors applet. A lot of people seem to be suggesting trying the indicator applets that you can find in synaptic but I haven't any experience myself.

EDIT: I found [`indicator-sensors`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators/48288#48288) that provides the functionality you need.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Classic with 11.04, so not using Unity

Comment: I've just tested this software http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/indicator-sensors-displays-cpu.html and it seems to do what you want, just add the ppa then install and run it.